# Why `Timeseries is not aligned` error occurred when importing data to Version 0.13.0 of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: import, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

What should I do if this error `Timeseries under path [root.cims] is not aligned, please set InsertPlan.isAligned() = false` occurs when importing data? I am now using Version 0.13.0 and is importing data to Apache IoTDB through the `import-csv.sh` script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use `docker` to redeploy a 0.13.4 version of Apache IoTDB. This bug will be solved in the new version, and the startup of IoTDB will be much faster using `docker-compose`.